# change Prototype to JQuery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, prototypejs

At the header I have the following

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function setConBal() {
    conBal = 1;
}
function readBalance() {
    new Ajax.Updater('tableBalance', '_Bet/PanelBalance1.aspx', { method: 'post', onComplete: setConBal });
}
function preReadBalance() {
    new Ajax.Updater('tableBalance', '_Bet/PanelBalance1.aspx', { method: 'post' });
}
</script>
```

Inside Body I have a div with ID = tableBalance
and the end of body tag I have this to call the JS functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">readBalance(); preReadBalance();</script>
```

The js functions are suppose to call PanelBalance1.aspx to generate a HTML table and put it into the div, it works fine when using prototype, but now I need to do the exact same thing using JQuery. I tried to change the function to JQuery syntax but it din't work.

```
function readBalance() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "_Bet/PanelBalance1.aspx",
        complete: function(r) {
        $('#tableBalance').html(r);
            setConBal();
        }
    });
}

function preReadBalance() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "_Bet/PanelBalance1.aspx"
    });

}
```

No error when I changed to this syntax but at the same time no Output either...
Am I doing this in a wrong way??

Comment: try changing complete for success

Comment: it works, by changing to success, but why??

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation and see the objects being passed to each event. data is in success only, however I'm not 100% sure that it isn't present as part of the jqXHR object in the complete event. Anyway, this works. Personally I never used complete before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function readBalance() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "_Bet/PanelBalance1.aspx",
        success: function(data) {
        $('#tableBalance').html(data);
            setConBal();
        }
    });
}
```